# E-commerce invoice in USD & receive payment in Bitcoin

Tags: buy-bitcoins, payment-processors, ecommerce, merchant-services

Is there an e-commerce plug-in or payment processing platform that facilitates the sequence detailed below?

1. Merchant accepts customer's online order
2. Customer's credit card is charged accordingly
3. The dollar amount of credit card charge is:

   1. Converted into bitcoin; ***or***
   2. Used to purchase the equivalent amount of bitcoins;
4. Value of customer's order (in bitcoin) posts to Merchant account
5. The customer receives the invoice in USD

Comment: credit card payments are reversible and bitcoins aren't. So any such service, if exists, would die very soon from fraud.

Answer (score 1):

[Coinvoice](https://coinvoice.com/) lets you invoice in USD and get paid in bitcoin. Sorry if you need the exact workflow described above. I'm not aware of many services that sell bitcoin and take credit card for payment.

Answer (score 0):

[Blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co) lets you invoice in any currency get paid in bitcoin. No signups and [directly into your wallet](https://medium.com/@blockonomics_co/peer-to-peer-no-signups-invoice-in-fiat-get-paid-in-bitcoin-f77772e4308b#.9x9axw43o).

Answer (score -1):

[Lamium](https://lamium.io) is a first decentralized bitcoin invoice payment service which allows you:

1. Merchant accepts customer's online order
2. Customer's credit card is charged accordingly
3. The dollar amount of credit card charge is converted into bit coin
4. The charge is used to purchase the equivalent in bit coins
5. Value of customer's order (in bit coin) posts to Merchant account
6. Customer receives invoice in USD